# How to get random samples of data within a defined interval of time in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So I have made an sql query to return a random set of data within a fixed interval of time. So far I was able to make it work with hours or days. but I can't figure out how to make it work with X hours, or X minutes.

Here is my code:

```
    def getSampleSQL_trades(self, symbol, interval=None, n_samples=5):
    query = "SELECT a, price, qty, time, Temp_Main.time_group " \
            "FROM " \
            "(SELECT a, price, qty, time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, min_time, time) as time_group " \
            "FROM {symbol}_trades," \
            "(SELECT MIN(time) as min_time " \
            "FROM {symbol}_trades) Temp) Temp_Main " \
            "INNER JOIN" \
            "(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, min_time, time) as time_group " \
            "FROM {symbol}_trades, " \
            "(SELECT MIN(time) as min_time " \
            "FROM {symbol}_trades) Temp " \
            "GROUP BY time_group " \
            "ORDER BY RAND() " \
            "LIMIT {n_s}) Temp2 " \
            "ON Temp2.time_group = Temp_Main.time_group " \
            "ORDER BY Temp_Main.time_group".format(symbol = symbol, n_s = n_samples)
    self.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=self.engine, index_col='a', parse_dates=['time'], columns=['time','price','qty'])
    self.disconnect()
    return df
```

is it possible to choose an interval in seconds? as if param `interval= 5 * (60)` then group data within a 5 minute interval.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Comment: @GMB thanks for the suggestion, I have just updated the tags.

Comment: For longer strings, consider Python's [triple quoted strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) and avoid the many quotes and line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was looking for, I used `TRUNCATE`

```
TRUNCATE(TIMESTAMPDIFF('Insert_Unit_here', time, new_time)/x, 0)
```

Where x is the unit value, so for 5-minute interval it should look like this:

```
TRUNCATE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_1, time_2)/5, 0)
```

cheers,